# How to Read Ternary Expansion of Cantor Set

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, ternary-expansion

My book<sup>1</sup> says: Let K be the set of real numbers that are sums of the series of the form $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{3^k}$ with ${a_k} \in \{0, 2\}$.

I can see that sum where ${a_k}=0$ goes to $0$: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{0}{3^k} = \frac{0}{3^1}+\frac{0}{3^2}+\frac{0}{3^3}+\frac{0}{3^4}.... = 0$$
and that the other sum for ${a_k}=2$ goes to $1$: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{3^k} = \frac{2}{3^1}+\frac{2}{3^2}+\frac{2}{3^3}+\frac{2}{3^4}.... = 1$$ Those are the only sums I see, since $a_k$ can only be $0$ or $2$. I am clearly reading the notation incorrectly. Can anyone help explain what the correct way to read the notation is?

<sup><sub>1</sub></sup> <sub>Elementary Topology Problem Textbook by O. Ya. Viro, O. A. Ivanov, N. Yu. Netsvetaev, V.M. Kharlamov</sub>

Comment: Each $a_k$ must come from the set $\{0,2\}$ but they don't all have to be the same.

Comment: How about $a_1=0,a_2=2,...$ and so on?  There are many others.

Comment: The numerators don't all have to be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much! These answer my question

Comment: @Dunham Does there need to be a pattern to the $a_k$s? Otherwise couldn't you just set the very first $a_k$ to 0, make the rest of them $a_k = 2$, and get 1/3 as the sum?

Comment: @outofthepark There could be a pattern, but there doesn't have to be. As you observe, $\frac13$ is in the set using coefficients $0, 2, 2, 2, 2,...$.

Comment: @outofthepark, if a number has a pattern, the number would be rational. This restriction would be missing a lot of possibilities (uncounatbly many).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> You probably understand at this point, but the claim is analogous to "Every real number in $[0, 1]$ can be written in the form$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{k}}{10^{k}}$$with $a_{k} \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$."